# Why can't I change pointers for methods?

Tags: delphi, pointers

I'm trying to change the value of a TNotifyEvent, same I do with integers with a pointer to it's value. But, when I try to do it to TNotifyEvent I get an exception (access violation). How can I do this ?

My goal is change the value of an external variable. Here is a code to explain here I get the error:

```
procedure TForm11.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LInteger: integer;
  LPinteger: ^Integer;

  LPNotify: ^TNotifyEvent;
  LNotify: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  LInteger := 10;
  LPinteger := @LInteger;
  LPinteger^ := 20; //It's ok, it make both variables with the same value
  Caption := Format('Pointer: %d | Value: %d', [LPinteger^, LInteger]);

  LNotify := Button3Click;
  LPNotify := @LNotify;
  LPNotify^ := nil; //Here I get the error

  Caption := Format('Pointer: %d | Value: %d', [Integer(LPNotify), Integer(@LNotify)]);
end;
```

Tks

Comment: "I get an exception". Please describe it verbatim.

Comment: Why are you trying to do it with all that unnecessary code? `var OldNotify: TNotifyEvent; begin OldNotify := Button3.OnClick; Button3.OnClick := nil; DoSomething; Button3.OnClick := OldNotify; end;` is sufficient. You want to print the address? Use `@Button3.OnClick`. You want to temporarily replace? `OldNotify := Button3.OnClick; Button3.OnClick :=  NewEvent; DoSomething; Button3.OnClick := OldNotify;`.

Comment: Try to have a look at TMethod http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TMethod I belive thats what you are looking for

Comment: @KenWhite Presumably he wants to take a reference to a variable.

Comment: @KenWhite This is just a pseudo code, the system problem is a different context.

Comment: "I have this problem with my code. Here's some code that's not my code (it's pseudo code), with no clear explanation of the problem. What's wrong?" isn't quite how we work here. :-)

Comment: @SaCi I thought the question was clear. You want to take a reference so you can modify a procedural type variable that is determined at runtime. I think it's a good question.

Comment: @KenWhite, what part of  my question you didn't understand ? To me it's simple and clear. I didn't ask for a solution or another approach for my code. What I want is to understand why I can change values in some pointer e not in others. My pseudo code was an example to make easier to you understand my point. @David, answered my question and it`s done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a different treatment of the `@` operator for variables of procedural type. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedural_Types) says:

> In some situations it is less clear how a procedural variable should
>   be interpreted. Consider the statement:
>
> ```
> if F = MyFunction then ...;
> ```
>
> In this case, the occurrence of F results in a function call; the
>   compiler calls the function pointed to by F, then calls the function
>   MyFunction, then compares the results. The rule is that whenever a
>   procedural variable occurs within an expression, it represents a call
>   to the referenced procedure or function. In a case where F references
>   a procedure (which doesn't return a value), or where F references a
>   function that requires parameters, the previous statement causes a
>   compilation error. To compare the procedural value of F with
>   MyFunction, use:
>
> ```
> if @F = @MyFunction then ...;
> ```
>
> @F converts F into an untyped pointer variable that contains an
>   address, and @MyFunction returns the address of MyFunction.
>
> To get the memory address of a procedural variable (rather than the
>   address stored in it), use @@. For example, @@F returns the address of
>   F.

This is your scenario. Instead of

```
LPNotify := @LNotify;
```

you need

```
LPNotify := @@LNotify;
```

If you compiled with the typed address option enabled, then the compiler would have rejected `LPNotify := @LNotify` as a type mismatch. I can find no sound explanation for Embarcadero continuing with typed address defaulting to disabled.

The final line of your function should probably be

```
Caption := Format(
  'Pointer: %d | Value: %d', 
  [Int64(@LNotify), Int64(TMethod(LPNotify^))]
);
```

I'm assuming that you use the 32 bit compiler for the `Int64` casts.